# Compare Methods in rpy2

Tags: python, list, for-loop, rpy2

I have an rpy2 script:

```
from rpy2.robjects.packages import importr
binom = importr('binom')
from rpy2 import robjects

robjects.r('''library(binom)
p = seq(0,1,.01)
coverage = binom.coverage(p, 10, method="bayes", type = "central")$coverage
''')
```

I'd like to use it to compare the results from a list of methods please:

```
methods = [("bayes", type = "central"),("asymptotic")]

for method in methods:
    robjects.globalenv["method"] = robjects.r(method)
    robjects.r('''library(binom)
    p = seq(0,1,0.01)
    coverage = binom.coverage(p, 10, method=method)$coverage
    ''')
```

The first line gives me:

```
invalid syntax
```

And I'd like to include the 'type' for the Bayes method please but when I drop that to get the syntax on my list I still get the error:

```
object 'bayes' not found
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`robjects.r()` receives a string so for this particular task you can just replace the word method with the right string. Using both quotes (single and double) will do the trick because `.replace()` will ditch the external quote and replace the text, keeping the single quote.

```
from rpy2.robjects.packages import importr
binom = importr('binom')
from rpy2 import robjects

methods = ["'bayes', type='central'","'asymptotic'"]
for method in methods:
    r_string = """library(binom)
    p = seq(0,1,0.01)
    coverage = binom.coverage(p, 10, method=TECHNIQUE)$coverage
    """.replace('TECHNIQUE',method)
    robjects.r(r_string)
```